# How can I change the view site link in Django admin, depending on which app is used?

Tags: django, django-users, django-apps

I am making a project where each client have their own app. This is because they have similar pages but not exactly the same so I think it's a good approach(I may be wrong) to just copy one app for each new client. I have not tried it yet, I am still planning for it. I see one problem with the view site link in the admin. I will let the clients use the admin. How can I set the view site link to the main page for the client? One way to solve it would be to leave it as is and have a function checking their user name and redirecting to the right app. But is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be a good idea to have applications generated for users as that's too much once you reached a specific amount of users.

> they have similar pages but not exactly the same

Then what you should do is to, after getting the user in your view, pass in a different context to your template. Something like:

```py
def my_view(request):
    # First assign different context to different users
    context = {'data': 'whatever each user gets', 'other': 'put in more than 1 data',}
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

> I will let the clients use the admin

That's not a good idea as the clients MUST be a superuser to view the admin site. Otherwise, you need to change the permissions of a superuser, make a separate superuser if you are the maintainer of the site, and all sorts of trouble. Just take some time and make your own templates.

Comment: It will be a limited amount of users. I have only one page for each user with a table in it, but the number of columns are different and also the headers which means I must construct the table dynamically. Maybe that is a better idea, if I can figure that out. You don't need to be a superuser to use admin. I can be staff also then I can give permissions easy.